# SQL Displaying data by joining 3 tables when data exits in 2 out of 3 table

Tags: sql, join

May I know how many joins should I have if I want to list the stud number, stud name, and the total number of course each student applied for?

Since the appnCseNum = cseNum and studNum = appcnStudNum

STUDENT(studNum, studName, studDOB, studAddress)

COURSE(cseNum, cseStartDate, cseEndDate)

APPLICATION(appcnCseNum, appcnStudNum)

```
SELECT STUDENT.studNum, STUDENT.studName, COUNT(APPLICATION.appcnCseNum) AS coursenum
FROM STUDENT JOIN APPLICATION
ON STUDENT.studNum= APPLICATION.appcnCseNum;
```

Do I need to have another join for the COURSE in order retrieve the result? because the error i got was "not a single-group group function".

If i do not include the count, if works perfectly fine.

```
SELECT APPLICANT.appNum, APPLICANT.appName, APPLICATION.appcnPosNum
FROM APPLICANT JOIN APPLICATION
ON APPLICANT.appNum  = APPLICATION.appcnAppNum;
```

--------------------------SOLVED--------------------

```
SELECT STUDENT.studNum, STUDENT.studName, COUNT(APPLICATION.appcnCseNum) AS coursenum
FROM STUDENT JOIN APPLICATION
ON STUDENT.studNum  = APPLICATION.appcnStudNum
GROUP BY STUDENT.studName, STUDENT.studName;
```

Comment: Which school are you from?

Comment: @realspirituals I'm from UWA.. please do not mistaken me, I'm not here to seek for any answers I hoping to know in such scenario do I have to use 3 join? because joining table is too confusing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No you'll not need another join to retrieve the result but however your query is wrong,try this

```
SELECT STUDENT.studNum, STUDENT.studName, COUNT(APPLICATION.appcnCseNum) AS coursenum
FROM STUDENT JOIN APPLICATION
ON STUDENT.studNum  = APPLICATION.appcnStudNum
GROUP BY STUDENT.studName;
```

Comment: thanks for the prompt reply, I've made a mistake in my question. I've updated it accordingly but the error i got was "not a single-group group function".

Comment: @SimM what do they mean by "not a Group By expression"?

Comment: saw your edit now in my code n made changes according to it.check it  nw

Comment: ok I know what made the error, the group by has to group both "Student.studNum" and "Student.studName" as they are from the same table.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/40333/discussion-between-sid-m-and-user2900611)